# Aggregate quantity columns per distinct date in table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I want to sum quantity column from first date in table (2016-02-17 in this table) until per each distinct date in the table. Result relation should contains sum of quantities per each distinct date in table.
how can I write a query for this in sql server?

```
 ID| quantity | date
---+----------+-----
18 |     6    | 2016-02-17 00:00:00.000
19 |     6    | 2016-02-17 00:00:00.000
18 |     4    | 2016-02-17 00:00:00.000
19 |     3    | 2016-02-18 00:00:00.000
18 |     1    | 2016-02-18 00:00:00.000
19 |     5    | 2016-02-18 00:00:00.000
18 |     6    | 2016-02-19 00:00:00.000
19 |     7    | 2016-02-19 00:00:00.000
18 |     8    | 2016-02-19 00:00:00.000
19 |     9    | 2016-02-19 00:00:00.000
```

**Expected output:**

```
|       Date | quantity |
|------------|----------|
| 2016-02-17 |       16 |
| 2016-02-18 |       25 |
| 2016-02-19 |       55 |
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: 2016-02-17 = 6+6+4 | 2016-02-18 = 6+6+4+5+1+3 | 2016-02-19 = 6+6+4+5+1+3+6+7+8+9

Comment: @eyvaz, Did you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Aggregate** function **SUM** with **GROUP BY** will give you the sum values for the `Distinct` dates.

```
SELECT Date, 
    SUM(quantity) OVER(ORDER BY Date) quantity
FROM(
    SELECT DATE, SUM(quantity) quantity
    FROM Your_Table 
    GROUP BY DATE
    )A
```

Check the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b356/5) for reference.

If you want the result for ID specific, use this. The **`PARTITION`** will make the difference.

```
SELECT Id, Date,
    SUM(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) quantity
FROM(
    SELECT Id, DATE, SUM(quantity) quantity
    FROM A 
    GROUP BY Id, DATE
    )A
```

Comment: This gives me just sum of quantity for each distinct date. I want sum of quantity for all row that has date smaller than each distinct date.

Comment: @eyvaz, Can you post your expected output in the Question?

Comment: 2016-02-17 = 6+6+4 | 2016-02-18 = 6+6+4+5+1+3 | 2016-02-19 = 6+6+4+5+1+3+6+7+8+9

Comment: It's works. But I have another question. What if I want to grouping the result by ID Column. I mean I want this result Separately for each value of ID Column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204488/discussion-between-eyvaz-and-dineshdb).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a subquery or CTE to use window functions with aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE, SUM(quantity) as day_quantity,
       SUM(SUM(quantity)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) as running_quantity
FROM Your_Table 
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE;
```

If you want the results ordered by date (as implied by your result set), you should include an explicit `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is

```
WITH
b as (
Select my_date,
SUM(quantity) Over(order by my_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) running_total
from main_table
)
SELECT my_date, max(running_total) running_total
from b group by dt
```